# Activity handles specific file types - how to read the data?

Tags: android

I need my activity to handle files of specific types downloaded from internet. Consider that browser successfully calls my activity. My activity gets Intent object. The question is how to read the downloaded file?

Intent.getData() returns Uri to my file as I understand.
Should I use HttpClient to get the file contents as described here?

[How to read files clicked in the Android web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933807/how-to-read-files-clicked-in-the-android-web-browser)

But then doesnt it reload the file again over the network, while the browser seem to already has loaded the file?

Answer (score 0):

Browser app will send you the Uri of local file. So no need to worry about any network related handling.

Comment: No, it actually sends Uri, starting from http.

Comment: Yes, URI can point to a file, for ex, file://sdcard/test.txt is also a Uri.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question.

intent.getData() returns Uri to remote file, not local. So as I understand the file is not saved locally at all, but my Activity is called instead. So it was right, the http client must be used to get the contents.

That's how it works:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
String uri = getIntent().getData().toString();
request.setURI(URI.create(uri)); 
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle files from the browser, I found two different ways, both may be correct:

1)

In the manifest for the activity, create an intent filter to handle already downloaded data, saved on the SD card or elsewhere: (This will also allow the browser to display your custom icon for the data type)

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="file" />
...
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in the activity: the uri will be of the form file://...

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    URI d = i.getData();
    Log.d("myactivity.onStart","URI: " + d.toString());
    // Do something with the locally saved data
}
```

---

2)

In the manifest for the activity, create an intent filter to handle urls. (This will also allow the browser to launch your activity rather than downloading the data.)

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
...
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in the activity, do the same thing, this time the URL will be http://...

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    URI d = i.getData();
    Log.d("myactivity.onStart","URI: " + d.toString());
    // Do something with the url, like download the data using an AsyncTask
}
```